# Do I need to unmarshal memory... twice?

Tags: c#, winapi, marshalling

I'm using the Win32 API for DHCP stuff, and following a code example from pinvoke.com I'm finding that the sample code kills my app when I am impersonating a user, and works fine when I am not. I believe it has something to do with Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem and/or Marshal.DestroyStructure but I don't understand why.

I'm a bit scared of a memory leak, so I want to do this right. Since I'm diving into the world of unmanaged, it is my understanding that memory needs to be manually cleaned up, hence the calls to Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem or Marshal.DestroyStructure. These methods work just fine if I am not calling this from within the enclosing Impersonation using block. Otherwise (by setting breakpoints) I see that the Dispose method of the Impersonation class is getting hit whenever the GetDHCPServers() method hits the mentioned death spots.

My question is - given how I am impersonating, do I even need to worry about using Marshal to clean up after myself, or is it redundant somehow? If I DO need to do something, what is a safe way to do so without exploding the enclosing Impersonation class?

Here is how I am impersonating:

```
 [PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
 public class Impersonation : IDisposable
 {
    private readonly SafeTokenHandle _handle;
    private readonly WindowsImpersonationContext _context;

    const int LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS = 9;

    // WIN32 API 
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private static extern bool LogonUser(String lpszUsername, String lpszDomain, String lpszPassword, int dwLogonType, int dwLogonProvider, out SafeTokenHandle phToken);

    public Impersonation(string domain, string username, string password)
    {
        var ok = LogonUser(username, domain, password,LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS, 0, out this._handle);

        if (!ok)
        {
            var errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            throw new ApplicationException(string.Format("Could not impersonate the elevated user.  LogonUser returned error code {0}.", errorCode));
        }

        this._context = WindowsIdentity.Impersonate(this._handle.DangerousGetHandle());
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this._context.Dispose();
        this._handle.Dispose();
    }
}
```

I then use this impersonation context when firing off my DHCP server finder, like so:

```
        using (new Impersonation(_domain, _user, _password))
        {
            DHCPScanner.GetDHCPServers();
        }
```

Here is where the problem happens and the unit test simply fails (no exceptions, it just stops running):

```
    [DllImport("dhcpsapi.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private static extern uint DhcpEnumSubnets(
        string ServerIpAddress,
        ref uint ResumeHandle,
        uint PreferredMaximum,
        out IntPtr EnumInfo,
        ref uint ElementsRead,
        ref uint ElementsTotal
    );

    public static void GetDHCPServers()
    {
        IntPtr svrs;
        uint dhcpResult = DhcpEnumServers(0, IntPtr.Zero, out svrs, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);

        if (dhcpResult == 0)
        {
            DHCP_SERVER_INFO_ARRAY dsArray = (DHCP_SERVER_INFO_ARRAY)Marshal.PtrToStructure(svrs, typeof(DHCP_SERVER_INFO_ARRAY));
            int size = (int)dsArray.NumElements;
            IntPtr outArray = dsArray.Servers;
            DHCPDS_SERVER[] serverList = new DHCPDS_SERVER[size];
            DHCP_SERVERS[] outlist = new DHCP_SERVERS[size];
            IntPtr current = outArray;
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                serverList[i] = new DHCPDS_SERVER();
                Marshal.PtrToStructure(current, serverList[i]);
                // the below line kills the process if I uncomment it
                //Marshal.DestroyStructure(current, typeof(DHCPDS_SERVER)); 
                current = (IntPtr)((int)current + Marshal.SizeOf(serverList[i]));
                outlist[i].ServerName = serverList[i].ServerName;
                outlist[i].ServerAddress = UInt32IPAddressToString(serverList[i].ServerAddress);
            }
            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(outArray); // <-- dies here too

        }

    }
```

Comment: Impersonation shouldn't affect memory management, though it might change the symptoms when a problem occurs.  The documentation says you need to use [DhcpRpcFreeMemory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363299%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to free the buffers returned by the DHCP Server Management API; this function doesn't seem to be exposed by the Marshal class, so you may need to P/Invoke it directly.

Comment: Hi Harry, this is good to know. I have been following the DHCP related items on pinvoke.net, and never was this mentioned. I will call this function when I get home tonight to see how it affects things. For reference, here is where I'm finding my functions since C++ is scary: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/dhcpsapi.DhcpEnumServers

Comment: If this doesn't fix it, there might simply be a bug in the DHCP Server Management API that is only exposed when impersonation is turned on; such a bug could easily have gone unnoticed.  You might find that you need to launch a subprocess in the context of the other user to do the work on your behalf.